# Should I write my parts in the correct octave?

Tags: arranging

I am a songwriter and a producer and I am learning how to compose and write music. I am going to be writing guitar, piano, bass and my own vocals. I notice that most sheet music of songs in the genre I am interested in usually have the male vocals transposed an octave higher up with the supporting harmony below. The bass lines are usually an octave higher in the transcriptions as well. I understand that this is for ease of reading. However, for my own arrangement purposes where I am going to be composing and arranging my own music and fitting my vocal parts in between the chords as opposed to on top of them, isn't it better to write things as they are since many times some of the harmony sits above my vocal part. I am looking to get into the best practice for this now. The notation will initially be for my own writing and arranging so it needs to be something I can practice and get comfortable with.

Here is an example. Lets say I start composing with my vocal melody which sits between C3 and middle C4 but I actually write it one octave higher as is most common. When I want to write my piano harmony part on the same grand staff the vocal will have taken that space on the treble clef so either I will also have to transpose the piano part or write it on another clef but for composing it is better to see both parts together.

Answer (score 5):

If you are writing for your own use, you can notate your music any way you want.

If you are writing parts for other people to play, you should write them in the correct octave according to the way they are conventionally written: bass or guitar parts an octave higher than they sound, male vocals an octave higher than they sound (when in treble clef), piccolo parts an octave lower than they sound, etc.

However you notate your music for your own use, it's just a couple of mouse clicks to  convert the parts so they are correct for others.

Comment: (Just to make it even more clear than is probably necessary, "correct octave" in this case meant *correct according to convention* octave, aka sounding an octave below written frequency as the answer indicates.)

Comment: @user45266 Thanks, I tend to assume everybody knows these kinds of things. Edited.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are writing an arrangement, not going for a single chart like published sheet music so forget what you see in sheet music. Sheet music is simply a single stave lead vocal which sometimes includes backgrounds, a two stave piano arrangement/reduction and guitar chord symbols on top which may or may not match what is in the piano arrangement.

Write a score and individual parts the way they should be written for a performer. Bass and guitar are transposing instruments and will sound an octave below written. For vocals use octave treble clefs for convenience if necessary and write the backgrounds on a separate chart for clarity if including the backgrounds on the lead vocal part will result in clutter.

Comment: THanks for the good info. If I have my vocal melody written an octave above and want to write and compose the piano part on the same grand staff, how is that going to be possible since the piano part will need that upper part that I am using for the vocal. Do you understand?

Comment: I have updated the question to include this info. Thanks again

Comment: @armani - Why write your vocals and piano part on the same grand staff? Unless you're writing a solo piano arrangement, I don't think this has ever been done. Even in classical music, the vocals and the piano parts are always on separate parts, so the vocals may overlap in range with the piano part but gets a separate line, system, and clef.

Comment: @Dekkadeci said it very well but I will add my thoughts too. Sometimes in sheet music the grand staff also contains the melody but in these cases the melody is written into and is a part of the piano arrangement, it is not a piano part with a melody superimposed over it. It is almost impossible to not overlap a piano “part” with a vocal line on a grand staff regardless of what octave you write them in because they live in the same register. Use a separate vocal line.

Comment: @Dekkadeci So I can look at one while I write the other. I thought this would be easier if they were on the same staff. Looking at intervals and writing as if it was a counterpoint exercise where you are given the melody and you compose the other parts. This is what I wanted to try doing with my vocal melody. Do you think this is silly?

Comment: @John almost impossible? If the arrangment is good they not need to overlap as the piano has several octaves and a vocal melody is only one note at a time. When recording I get a much nicer balance across the frequency spectrum when the vocal sits in between the music... not on top of it. In proper arranging you arrange your piano part for the vocal and where it will sit so they all have their own frequency space on the recording else you have to use more EQ and panning to make the vocal clearer yielding a less natural result.

Comment: @John Here is an arrangement I did where the piano completely surrounds the vocal but never plays on top of it https://ibb.co/gJpQvZK. When the vocal is playing the harmony is always supporting it either below or above just as in 4 part writng where each voice has its own space.

Comment: Is this a piano part or a piano/vocal in 2 staves? If the vocal is the treble clef then there are areas where the bass clef crosses above the treble and also where notes are simultaneously sounding in both staves. If you take the treble clef 8vb into account then it overlaps even more, unless you meant 8va for the treble clef.

Comment: @armani Your first comment was hidden and I just saw it. I never said the vocal should sit on top of the accompaniment, quite the contrary. Your comment is contradictory, you say they not need overlap then you say the vocal should sit in between the music, isn’t that overlapping? You have been offered advice which you asked for but in the end it is your music, do as you see fit.

Comment: @John, I understand what you mean. By not overlapping, I meant that if my melody is c3 - c4 then the chords should be mostly out of this octave. Overlap means one on top of the other as if I play the chords in the same octave as the melody. Hope that clarifies. Not contradictory at all. "In between" means what I sent you a link of with an arrangement I did. The accompaniment sits either below or above not.. not "overlapping. THat is why I added an example as words sometimes can sound contradictory.

Comment: To answer your question, this is a piano part with a vocal melody on top.. I may have made a mistake but basically the top melody is supposed to be one octave lower.. did I get this wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125039/discussion-between-armani-and-john-belzaguy).